# How can I programmatically add playlists or views to iTunes?

Tags: itunes, playlists

Is there a way to programmatically interface with iTunes to add new playlists or smart views?

For example, say I download 10 new mp3 files from a website, is there a way of programmatically adding this list of mp3s to a new playlist called "New Album xx"?  A new smart view could be okay too if this is easier.

More specifically, this is for a Windows project, so the way of doing this should be platform independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does offer a COM-based SDK for automating iTunes with Windows. It's not the greatest (for example, I think you have to make sure iTunes.exe is running in a desktop session and several commands can cause dialogs to popup and block your automation), but it does let you do things like create new play lists and add songs.

[Install Here](http://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunescomsdk.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on a Mac... I think you can do this with AppleScript, this [link](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/scripts06.php) might be useful